# Capturing the name of the file pointed by a symbolic link in a variable

Tags: shell, zsh, symlink

Say I have a symbolic link:

```
/path/to/foo->/path/to/some_file.txt
```

Say I have a shell variable `x=/path/to/foo`, how can I get `some_file.txt` in a shell variable `y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `zsh`,

```
y=${x:A:t}
```

would expand to the tail of the absolute path of `$x`. So it would be `some_file.txt` unless `some_file.txt` is itself a symlink to something else.

Otherwise, you can use `zsh` `zstat` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/zstat
zstat -A y +link -- $x && y=$y:t
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`readlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) to get the pathname of the target file and then [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) to extract its filename:

```
y="$(basename -- "$(readlink -- "$x")")"
```